# problem with .blur function using jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-effects

I have an application which zooms in image on `focus()` and zooms out on `blur()`. I have read the original image size and added 15px to it in order to create the zoom in effect, which works fine. The problem is with the zoom out effect where I'm trying to pass the original image size that I have read to `.blur()` but with no luck. Could any one help me solve this issue?

Comment: go to your demo and paste your css, html and jQuery code in appropriate editor given by jsFidle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Here is a working demo](http://www.jsfiddle.net/XaKqq/10/) of the following code.**

First, you weren't calling the `$.data()` method on `orgW` and `orgH` in your `.blur()` function.  Also, I've altered your `.blur()` function to have a similar implementation to your `.focus()` function in order to get the zoom out to work:

```
$('button:has(img)').blur(function() {

    if (timer !== null) clearTimeout(timer);

    var $image = $(this).find('img');

    $image.each(function() {
        $(this).animate({
            'width': $.data(this, 'orgW') + 'px',
            'height': $.data(this, 'orgH') + 'px',
        }, 500);
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `'+=15'` and `'-=15'` in the animation function. No need to store width and height.

```
$('button:has(img)').focus(function() {
    $(this).find('img').animate({
        width: '+=15',
        height: '+=15'
    }, 500);
});

$('button:has(img)').blur(function() {
    $(this).find('img').animate({
        'width': '-=15',
        'height': '-=15'
    }, 0);
});
```

[Demo](http://www.jsfiddle.net/ucmrq/2/)

EDIT: Now it should work.

Comment: Your demo decreases the width double on each `blur()` but I'm not sure why.  Tested in Chrome 9.

Comment: Yeah I noticed the same. I'm not sure why because according to api it should work fine. EDIT: Yeah the problem is that the animation must go all the way through before calling blur.